# IE 9 Like Button Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am not sure when this started, but I am getting the following error recently in IE 9:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'some' 
DIcn3oT9qlo.js, line 41 character 1923

Here is some sample code that can reproduce the error (after changing to use a valid APP ID)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + "YOUR APP ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<script language="javascript">
        document.write('  <div id="like"><fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com" send="false" layout="button_count" width="53" show_faces="false"></fb:like></div>');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It also does not work for IE=EmulateIE7.  It does work if I change X-UA-Compatible to be IE=9.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is broken?

Any help that can be offered is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

i did, and i've fixed it, apparently it's a recent thing... dunno why it's happening, it worked before for me.

Comment: I looked everywhere for an answer and this was the only thing that worked. Thanks!!!